# Primitive Pythagorean triples and the limit of two counting functions, is this limit equal to $0$ or not?

Tags: prime-numbers, pythagorean-triples

For every $c \in \mathbb N$ either there exists at least one $(a,b) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ or such $(a,b)$ do not exist.

We could define counting function $C$ to mean $C(n)= \text{the number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$}$ and $\text {$(a,b,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple for $1 \leq c \leq n$}$

Now, the other counting function $P$ can be defined to mean $P(n)=\text{the number of numbers of the form $a+b+c-1$ or $a+b+c+1$}$ such that either $a+b+c-1$ or $a+b+c+1$ (or both) are primes for $1 \leq c \leq n$ and $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple

It should be noted that if both $a+b+c-1$ and $a+b+c+1$ are primes then only one of them is counted in $P(n)$.

If very very often either $a+b+c-1$ or $a+b+c+1$ (or both) are primes then it seems possible to have $$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \dfrac {P(n)}{C(n)} >0$$ but this seems to be highly improbable and would defy even the most optimistic heuristics that would opt for this result to hold.

> So if $$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \dfrac {P(n)}{C(n)} =0$$ then how to prove that?

Some ideas?

Comment: @Peter Yes, we count triples such that either $a+b+c-1$ or $a+b+c+1$ is prime (or both).

Comment: but with the additional condition that $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive pythagorean triple and $c$ is limited by $n$. OK, I understood.

Comment: @Peter Yes. I didn´t do computational experiments for this question, if you compute something let me know.

Comment: I will try. Can we assume that $a$ is the odd leg ? What I mean , do $(3/4)$ aqnd $(4/3)$ only count once ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, we view (3,4,5) and (4,3,5) as exactly the same triple, if that´s what you ask.

Comment: Yes, that was my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105420/discussion-between-ante-and-peter).

Answer (score 1):

I developed a formula that generates all Pythagorean triples where $GCD(A,BC)=2x-1,x\in\mathbb{N}$ ...which includes all primitives.

$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$

where $n$ is a set number and $k$ is a member number or "count" within a set as seen in the sample below.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &143,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281 & 253,204,325 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Only $Set_1$ contains only primitives (note $C-B=(2n-1)^2=1$). In all other sets, a multiple is generated any time any $k$ is divisible by a factor of $(2n-1).\quad$  $C$ can be prime in any of the sets but only in $Set_1$ can $A$ be prime because $A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\quad=\quad (2n-1)(2n-1+k)\quad$ and if $n>1$ then $A$ is composite.

In the first $15$ members of $Set_1$ where $A+B+C\pm1\lt 1000$, we have $5$ prime pairs and $8$ single primes and, like primes anywhere, they seem to get scarcer with altitude. Here the triples and counts ()[].

$$
(3,4,5)[2]\quad
(5,12,13)[2]\quad
(7,24,25)[1]\quad
(9,40,41)[1]\quad
(11,60,61)[2]\quad
(13,84,85)[1]\quad
(15,112,113)[1]\quad
(17,144,145)[1]\quad
(19,180,181)[2]\quad
(21,220,221)[0]\quad
(23,264,265)[1]\quad
(25,312,313)[1]\quad
(27,364,365)[0]\quad
(29,420,421)[2]\quad
(31,480,481)[1]\quad
$$

We have infinite sets and only $Set_1$ can contain double primes. Granted the value of $C$ grows faster in the other sets for a given $k$ but, for given limits on the value of $C$, we still have a growing finite number of double primes $Set_1$ divided a faster growing number of single primes only in the other sets.  Therefore, if you can formalize the logic, I think you may be able to prove your conjecture that the limit of $\frac{P}{C}=0$.

Update:$\quad$ I was concerned about multiples outnumbering primitives as the values of $(2n-1)$ composites got ever larger and had more and more factors that could divide $k$ but I remembered something which allows us to ignore $(2n-1)$ composites completely.

$(2n-1)$ generates all primes greater than $2$ so there are an infinite number of sets where $(2n-1)$ is prime. To avoid generating multiples, if $(2n-1)$ is prime, we need only modify the formula so that it repeatedly generates $\big((2n-1)-1\big)$ triples, then skips one.

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&2(2n-1)\bigg(k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(2n-2)}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)&\qquad\\
&B=&2(2n-1)\bigg(k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(2n-2)}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)&\qquad+2\bigg(k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(2n-2)}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&2(2n-1)\bigg(k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(2n-2)}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)&\qquad+2\bigg(k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{(k-1)}{(2n-2)}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)^2
 \end{align*}

For any $Set_n, (n>1\land (2n-1) \text{ is prime})$, this formula will skip multiples and generate a set containing only primitives. Since there are infinite triples in each set, each will contain an infinite number of prime $C$-values. Also, there are infinite sets where $(2n-1)$ is prime so we effectively have $$\frac{\infty}{\infty^2}$$.

This makes no sense mathematically because $\infty^2=\infty$ but we are dealing with finite counts and it is easy to see that the limit approaches this $philosophical$ $\frac{x}{x^2}=0$.

Two more trivia that may not help but are interesting. $\mathbf{(1)}$ All primes greater than the sub-primes $2\&3$ take the form of $6x\pm1$ while all C-values take the form of $4n+1$. This means that $C$ will never have the values of $7,11,19,23,31,43,...$ but there may be a prime whenever the two can generate the same number. $\mathbf{(2)}$ There can be multiple triples for some composite $C$-values but not if $C$ is prime. This means that a prime $C$-value in any set will be unique among all sets.

Good luck in your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

I was writing a program to explore your conjecture and found you already awarded the bounty. I wrote it in Chipmunk BASIC but that doesn't make it all bad.

The output looks something like this keeping in mind this is not F(m,n) but rather F(n,k):

$
\text{>run}\\
\text{Enter highest C value? 100}\\
\text{K9 (highest k value is set  1) is  6   where C = 85 }\\
\text{double f( 1 , 1 ) = 3 4 5  }\\
\text{double f( 1 , 2 ) = 5 12 13  }\\
\text{f( 1 , 4 ) = 9 40 41  }\\
\text{double f( 1 , 5 ) = 11 60 61  }\\
\text{f( 2 , 1 ) = 15 8 17  }\\
\text{f( 2 , 2 ) = 21 20 29  }\\
\text{f( 3 , 1 ) = 35 12 37  }\\
\text{f( 3 , 2 ) = 45 28 53  }\\
\text{f( 3 , 3 ) = 55 48 73 }\\
\text{Pair prime count = 3  Single prime count = 6  }\\
$

For  $C\le1000000$, the last line was:
Pair prime count = $101$   Single prime count = $331912$

```
 100 rem find double primes A&C vs single primes C
 110 print "Enter highest C value";
 120 input h1
 130 rem generate highest k value in set 1
 140 k9 = int((-1+sqr(2*h1-1))/2)
 150 rem generate highest C-value in set 1
 160 c9 = 1+2*(k9+k9^2)
 170 print "K9 (highest k value is set  1) is  " k9;
 180 print "  where C = " c9
 190 for n1 = 1 to k9
 200    for k1 = 1 to k9
 210       b1 = 2*(2*n1-1)*k1+2*k1^2
 220 rem   generate C
 230       c1 = (2*n1-1)^2+2*(2*n1-1)*k1+2*k1^2
 240 rem   generate A
 250       a1 = (2*n1-1)^2+2*(2*n1-1)*k1
 260 rem   test for C > limit
 270       if c1 > c9
 280          k1 = k9
 290          goto 650
 300       endif
 310       f3 = 0
 320 rem   find factors of C1 where f3 is C-factor count
 330       for f0 = 3 to int(sqr(c1)) step 2
 340          if c1/f0 = int(c1/f0) then 
 350 rem          count factors
 360              f3 = f3+1
 370          endif
 380       next f0
 390 rem   if no factors, C is prime 
 400       if f3 = 0
 410 rem    if set 1, test for A is prime  where f1 is A-factor count
 420          if n1 = 1
 430             f1 = 0
 440             for f0 = 3 to int(sqr(a1))
 450                 if a1/f0 = int(a1/f0)
 460                    f1 = f1+1
 470                 endif
 480             next f0
 490 rem         if A is prime add to Pair count P0
 500             if f1 = 0
 510 rem print double prime Pair
 520     print "double f( " n1 ", " k1 ") = " a1 b1 c1
 530                p0 = p0+1
 540             else 
 550 rem print single prime Pair
 560     print "f( " n1 ", " k1 ") = " a1 b1 c1
 570                c0 = c0+1
 580             endif
 590          else 
 600 rem print single prime Pair
 610     print "f( " n1 ", " k1 ") = " a1 b1 c1
 620             c0 = c0+1
 630          endif
 640       endif
 650    next k1
 660 next n1
 670 print "Pair prime count = " p0,"Single prime count = " c0
```